# ContextMenu Fails To Remove Row From ListView With Custom Adapter

Tags: java, android, listview, android-adapter, android-contextmenu

**The Problem is:** My ContextMenu Fails to Remove a Row from ListView with a Custom Adapter and 
the app crashes with the error: UnsupportedOperationException, see Logcat output.

I have done Google searches and searched stackoverflow. None of the information I have found solves this problem.

**My Question is:** What is wrong with my code?
Please provide the correct code to solve this problem.

Java Code:

```
        public class TestActivity extends ListActivity {

        private String itemNameArray[];
        private String dateArray[];

        private ListView listview;
        CustomListViewAdapter customListViewAdapter;

                        @Override
                        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                            setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

                            registerForContextMenu(getListView());

                            root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "/ListTestFiles";
                            getDir(root);

            listview = getListView();

            name=itemNameArray;
            lastmod=dateArray;

            customListViewAdapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this, name, lastmod);

            listview.setAdapter(customListViewAdapter);

      } // End of onCreate code.


        class CustomListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
            Context context;
            String[] nameArray;
            String[] modifiedArray;

            CustomListViewAdapter(Context c, String[] name, String[] lastmod)
            {
                super(c, R.layout.layout_item_view, R.id.rowtext, name);
                this.context = c;
                this.nameArray = name;
                this.modifiedArray = lastmod;
            }

            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
            {
                LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_item_view, parent, false);

                TextView myName;
                TextView myLastMod;

                myName=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.rowtext);
                myName.setText(nameArray[position]);

                myLastMod=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView6);
                myLastMod.setText(modifiedArray[position]);

                return row;
            }
        }


         @Override
         public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                         ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
             super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
                 MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
                 inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
         }

        @Override
        public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem itemMenu) {

            final AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)itemMenu.getMenuInfo();

            switch (itemMenu.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.context_menu_rename:
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Rename", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                case R.id.context_menu_delete:
                    // NOTE TESTING the line of code below caused a runtime error: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
                    customListViewAdapter.remove(customListViewAdapter.getItem(info.position));
                    customListViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "position = " + info.position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Delete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                return true;

                return super.onContextItemSelected(itemMenu);
        }
    }
}
```

Logcat output:

```
11-13 10:45:21.229  21432-21432/com.testing.listapp D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
    --------- beginning of crash
11-13 10:45:21.246  21432-21432/com.testing.listapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.testing.listapp, PID: 21432
    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
            at java.util.AbstractList.remove(AbstractList.java:638)
            at java.util.AbstractList$SimpleListIterator.remove(AbstractList.java:75)
            at java.util.AbstractCollection.remove(AbstractCollection.java:229)
            at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.remove(ArrayAdapter.java:244)
            at com.testing.listapp.TestActivity.onContextItemSelected(TestActivity.java:5468)
            at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2905)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DialogMenuCallback.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:4701)
            at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:761)
            at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
            at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:904)
            at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:894)
            at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuDialogHelper.onClick(MenuDialogHelper.java:167)
            at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:1082)
            at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:305)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1146)
            at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3053)
            at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3860)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your work:

```
public class TestActivity extends ListActivity { 
    private ArrayList<String> itemNameArray;
     private ArrayList<String> dateArray;
     private ListView listview;
     CustomListViewAdapter customListViewAdapter; 

    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
     registerForContextMenu(getListView());
 String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "/ListTestFiles";
     getDir(root);

     listview = getListView();

     CustomListViewAdapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this, itemNameArray, dateArray);
     listview.setAdapter(customListViewAdapter);
     }
     // End of onCreate code. class

     CustomListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> { 
    ArrayList<String> nameArray;
     ArrayList<String> modifiedArray; CustomListViewAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<String> name, ArrayList<String> lastmod) {
     super(c, 0, name); 
     this.nameArray = name;
     this.modifiedArray = lastmod;
     } 
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
    LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(parent.get context());
     convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_item_view, parent, false); 
    TextView myName; 
    TextView myLastMod;
     myName=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.rowtext);
     myName.setText(nameArray.get(position));
     myLastMod=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView6);
     myLastMod.setText(modifiedArray.get(position));
     return convertView;
     }
     }

     @Override
     public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) { 
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo); 
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu); 
    }

     @Override 
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem itemMenu) {

    switch (itemMenu.getItemId()) { 
    case R.id.context_menu_rename:
     Toast.makeText(this, "Rename", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     break; 
    case R.id.context_menu_delete: itemNameArray.remove(listView.getSelectedItemPosition());
    dateArray.remove(listView.getSelectedItemPosition()); customListViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
     break; 
    }
    return true;
     }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove items from **nameArray** and **modifiedArray** at that particular position, then notify **adapter** of dataset changes.

I see. One big mistake is using fixed size array in a place that requires dynamic size array.

Change your

```
String nameArray[];
String modifiedArray[];
```

to

```
ArrayList<String> nameArray;
 ArrayList<String> modifiedArray;
```

Comment: 1. Are you saying to remove all code for nameArray and modifiedArray? 
2. If I do that my ListView will not have any data to show in the TextViews.

Comment: Remove that particular item found at that position. Since you have 2 arraylists: nameArray and modifiedArray, you must remove on each array, item at that position.

Comment: Change these too: private String itemNameArray[]; private String dateArray[];

Comment: 1. My ListView including class CustomListViewAdapter with its String arrays has been working well to show the ListView and all the Rows filled with data. 
2. My goal Now is to remove the entire Row selected by a long click on the Row. 
3. I am not trying to remove Only the data from the TextViews in the Row. 
4. It looks like your code below is attempting to remove Only the data from the TextViews in the Row: 

                itemNameArray.remove(listView.getSelectedItemPosition()); 
                dateArray.remove(listView.getSelectedItemPosition());

Comment: I think, you don't understand!!!!!!!!!!! Array of [] such as String[] is for fixed size array !!!;;!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! You cannot shrink or expand its size!!!!!!!! To increase or reduce the number of items in an array, you must use array of Collections package such as ArrayList. !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Thanks for the code it solved the problem. As you suggested, I replaced String[]  with ArrayList<String>. I also needed to modify some of my other code to work with it.